# Android Gradle plugin 0.7.0: "duplicate files during packaging of APK"

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Using Android Gradle plugin 0.7.0 with the following `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://android-rome-feed-reader.googlecode.com/svn/maven2/releases" }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '18.1.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        defaultFlavor {
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        instrumentTest.setRoot('src/instrumentTest')
    }
}

configurations {
    apt
}

ext.androidAnnotationsVersion = '2.7.1';

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'

    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'

    compile 'com.google.code.android-rome-feed-reader:android-rome-feed-reader:1.0.0-r2'
    compile 'org.jdom:jdom:1.1.1-android-fork'

    apt "com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
    compile "com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.47'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.47'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:actionbarsherlock:4.3.1@aar'

    compile 'com.google.code.geocoder-java:geocoder-java:0.15'

    compile files('libs/CWAC-Pager.jar')
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    aptOutput = file("${project.buildDir}/source/apt_generated/${variant.dirName}")
    println "****************************"
    println "variant: ${variant.name}"
    println "manifest:  ${variant.processResources.manifestFile}"
    println "aptOutput:  ${aptOutput}"
    println "****************************"

    variant.javaCompile.doFirst {
        println "*** compile doFirst ${variant.name}"
        aptOutput.mkdirs()
        variant.javaCompile.options.compilerArgs += [
                '-processorpath', configurations.apt.getAsPath(),
                '-AandroidManifestFile=' + variant.processResources.manifestFile,
                '-s', aptOutput
        ]
    }
}
```

gives the error `Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt`:

```
WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0.4 is ignored for defaultFlavorDebug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0.4 is ignored for defaultFlavorRelease as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
Deprecated dynamic property: "aptOutput" on "com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated@5705013c", value: "/Users/david/Developer...".
****************************
variant: defaultFlavorDebug
manifest:  /Users/david/Developer/.../build/manifests/defaultFlavor/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
aptOutput:  /Users/david/Developer/.../build/source/apt_generated/defaultFlavor/debug
****************************
Deprecated dynamic property "aptOutput" created in multiple locations.
****************************
variant: defaultFlavorRelease
manifest:  /Users/david/Developer/.../build/manifests/defaultFlavor/release/AndroidManifest.xml
aptOutput:  /Users/david/Developer/.../build/source/apt_generated/defaultFlavor/release
****************************
:TravelGuard:compileDefaultFlavorDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:TravelGuard:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:TravelGuard:preDefaultFlavorDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:TravelGuard:preDefaultFlavorReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:TravelGuard:prepareComProlificinteractiveActionbarsherlock431Library UP-TO-DATE
:TravelGuard:prepareComViewpagerindicatorLibrary241Library UP-TO-DATE
:TravelGuard:prepareDefaultFlavorDebugDependencies
:TravelGuard:compileDefaultFlavorDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:TravelGuard:compileDefaultFlavorDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:TravelGuard:generateDefaultFlavorDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:TravelGuard:mergeDefaultFlavorDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:TravelGuard:mergeDefaultFlavorDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:TravelGuard:processDefaultFlavorDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:TravelGuard:processDefaultFlavorDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:TravelGuard:generateDefaultFlavorDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:TravelGuard:compileDefaultFlavorDebugJava
*** compile doFirst defaultFlavorDebug
/Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/service/TravelGuardService.java:53: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TravelGuardPrefs_
location: class com.travelguard.service.TravelGuardService
    TravelGuardPrefs_ travelGuardPrefs;
    ^
/Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/ui/CategoriesActivity.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class AssistanceFragment_
location: package com.travelguard.ui.fragments
import com.travelguard.ui.fragments.AssistanceFragment_;
                                   ^
/Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/ui/CategoriesActivity.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class CategoryFragment_
location: package com.travelguard.ui.fragments
import com.travelguard.ui.fragments.CategoryFragment_;
                                   ^
/Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/ui/CategoriesActivity.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ContactFragment_
location: package com.travelguard.ui.fragments
import com.travelguard.ui.fragments.ContactFragment_;
                                   ^
/Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/ui/CountriesActivity.java:25: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TravelGuardPrefs_
location: package com.travelguard.service
import com.travelguard.service.TravelGuardPrefs_;
                              ^
/Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/ui/CountriesActivity.java:44: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TravelGuardPrefs_
location: class com.travelguard.ui.CountriesActivity
    TravelGuardPrefs_ travelGuardPrefs;
    ^
/Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/ui/InstructionsActivity.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class AssistanceFragment_
location: package com.travelguard.ui.fragments
import com.travelguard.ui.fragments.AssistanceFragment_;
                                   ^
/Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/ui/InstructionsActivity.java:19: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ContactFragment_
location: package com.travelguard.ui.fragments
import com.travelguard.ui.fragments.ContactFragment_;
                                   ^
/Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/ui/InstructionsActivity.java:21: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class InstructionsFragment_
location: package com.travelguard.ui.fragments
import com.travelguard.ui.fragments.InstructionsFragment_;
                                   ^
/Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/ui/MainActivity.java:36: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TravelGuardPrefs_
location: package com.travelguard.service
import com.travelguard.service.TravelGuardPrefs_;
                              ^
/Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/ui/MainActivity.java:40: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class AssistanceFragment_
location: package com.travelguard.ui.fragments
import com.travelguard.ui.fragments.AssistanceFragment_;
                                   ^
/Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/ui/MainActivity.java:41: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ContactFragment_
location: package com.travelguard.ui.fragments
import com.travelguard.ui.fragments.ContactFragment_;
                                   ^
/Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/ui/MainActivity.java:55: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TravelGuardPrefs_
location: class com.travelguard.ui.MainActivity
    TravelGuardPrefs_ travelGuardPrefs;
    ^
/Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/ui/TermsActivity.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TravelGuardPrefs_
location: package com.travelguard.service
import com.travelguard.service.TravelGuardPrefs_;
                              ^
/Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/ui/TermsActivity.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TravelGuardPrefs_
location: class com.travelguard.ui.TermsActivity
    TravelGuardPrefs_ travelGuardPrefs;
    ^
Note: Starting AndroidAnnotations annotation processing
Note: AndroidManifest.xml file found: /Users/david/Developer/.../build/manifests/defaultFlavor/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
Note: Number of files generated by AndroidAnnotations: 22
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.service.SmartTravellerService_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.service.SmartTravellerWebservice_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.service.TravelGuardPrefs_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.service.TravelGuardService_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.service.TravelGuardWebservice_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.AdviceActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.CategoriesActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.ContactDetailActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.ContactListActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.ContactTravelGuardActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.CountriesActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.InformationActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.InstructionsActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.MainActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.TermsActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.TravelGuardActivity_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.fragments.AdviceDetailFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.fragments.AdviceFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.fragments.AssistanceFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.fragments.CategoryFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.fragments.ContactFragment_
Note: Generating source file: com.travelguard.ui.fragments.InstructionsFragment_
Note: Time measurements: [Whole Processing = 913 ms], [Generate Sources = 358 ms], [Extract Manifest = 163 ms], [Process Annotations = 158 ms], [Extract Annotations = 120 ms], [Validate Annotations = 82 ms], [Find R Classes = 28 ms],
Note: Time measurements: [Whole Processing = 0 ms],
Note: Time measurements: [Whole Processing = 0 ms],
warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[androidManifestFile]'
Note: /Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/ui/ContactDetailActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/david/Developer/.../src/main/java/com/travelguard/service/SmartTravellerService.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:TravelGuard:preDexDefaultFlavorDebug UP-TO-DATE
:TravelGuard:dexDefaultFlavorDebug
:TravelGuard:processDefaultFlavorDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:TravelGuard:validateDebugSigning
:TravelGuard:packageDefaultFlavorDebug
Error: duplicate files during packaging of APK /Users/david/Developer/.../build/apk/TravelGuard-defaultFlavor-debug-unaligned.apk
    Path in archive: META-INF/LICENSE.txt
    Origin 1: /Users/david/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/964cd74171f427720480efdec40a7c7f6e58426a/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
    Origin 2: /Users/david/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/397f4731a9f9b6eb1907e224911c77ea3aa27a8b/commons-codec-1.2.jar
:TravelGuard:packageDefaultFlavorDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':TravelGuard:packageDefaultFlavorDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
    File 1: /Users/david/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/964cd74171f427720480efdec40a7c7f6e58426a/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
    File 2: /Users/david/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/964cd74171f427720480efdec40a7c7f6e58426a/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 21.957 secs
```

Things were working fine this morning before I updated Android Studio. Any ideas?

EDIT: I was able to temporarily fix it by running commands like

```
zip -d spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar META-INF/notice.txt
```

until all the duplicate errors went away.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673888/duplicate-files-copied-android-studio-0-4-0

Comment: This seems to be bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61573. I don't know why it's only started being troublesome for you in this release.

Comment: stuck with the same problem. Decided to stay on Android Studio 0.3.7 and gradle plugin 0.6.3 until bug is resolved

Comment: You should be clear of your wordings: You aren't using gradle 0.7.0 - it is the android gradle plugin. Which uses gradle (with wrapper) in version 1.9.0.

Wrong wordings will lead to confusing - besides of the given context.

Comment: They just release 0.7.1 which supposedly fixes this: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Comment: Please note the `pickFirst` option available since [Gradle 0.9.1](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system).

Answer (score 475, accepted):

### As of Android Studio version 0.8.14

You should add:

```
 android {
     packagingOptions { 
         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
         exclude '...'
     }
 }
```

to your `build.gradle` file.

#### History:

According to comment 14 in this bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36982149#comment14 this is a bug in v0.7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin, and is due to be fixed soon in 0.7.1.

Here are the notes from that bug about the addition for 0.7.1:

0.7.1 is out with the fix for this.

The DSL to exclude files is:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```

You can add as many exclude statement as you want. The value is the archive path. No wildcard or glob support yet.

**Filenames "LICENSE.txt" and "NOTICE.txt" are case sensitive. Please try out with "license.txt" and "notice.txt" as well.**

Comment: See my temporary fix above

Comment: Version 0.7.1 of the plugin is out now and the above solution works now.

Comment: Thanks! I also had to exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' ;)

Comment: @wolfovercats you add this to your build.gradle, you already have a android{} block, just add the packagingOptions block to it

Comment: So, apparently it's case-sensitive. I had to use META-INF/notice.txt instead to get past this issue. But, thanks for the answer! You saved me a lot of trouble!

Comment: Day by day I am astonished by how programmers could have been remotely productive before stackoverflow arrived. Thanks for the fix! I had to exclude META-INF/LICENSE and /NOTICE instead. (No txt, even on latest gradle.)

Comment: things like this would make you stop using great tools like gradle... pre-SO. Thanks!

Comment: What file i should edit and where it can be found? thanks, Eyal.

Comment: @praneetloke please help me : How to exclude META-INF/notice.txt?

Comment: Here's an example build.gradle that includes the solution: https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android/blob/master/onebusaway-android/build.gradle  You can add multiple files to exclude.

Comment: @um.anusorn Sean has given you a good example for a gradle file that excludes these files from libraries during packaging. This is what I have in mine:  packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependenices.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }

Comment: Still prevalent bug in v0.12 of built tools.. Just saying

Comment: Added the .txt extensions to /LICENSE and /NOTICE. Fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @domenukk We had less complicated tools by our side!

Comment: 26.04.2015 - Still need that in Android Studio v1.1.0

Comment: Do you mean Android Studio 0.8.14?

Comment: Had to do this version 1.4.1 - after adding Spring for Android and GSON to my Gradle file. Would not work unless the 'NOTICE' and 'LICENSE' were lowercase - 'notice.txt', 'license.txt'

Comment: Not worked for me, still shows Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android. In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages

Comment: You can also use [pickFirst](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43534151/1121497). Consider commenting that in your solution. Thanks!

Comment: a regex to relieve the pain `excludes += ['META-INF/*']`

Comment: 2021-05-22:  Android 4.x and I think I don't need this anymore.  Finally.  This has been in my gradle file for 7 years!

Comment: I know this is old, but wildcards work now (I'm using Gradle 7.4) for example pickFirst 'lib/x86/*.so'

Answer (score 149):

In my case I had to include several additional exclusions.  It appears it doesn't like Regular expressions which would've made this a nice one-liner.

```html
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: I only needed `LICENSE` and `NOTICE` after I added `commons-lang3`.

Comment: This one helped me (I have AndroidAnnotations + Spring REST template). With having to add such hacks this IntelliJ product dreadfully starts to resemble Eclipse...

Comment: Don't know which one affects, but this is really helpful.

Comment: Not worked for me, still shows  Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.          In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages

Answer (score 46):

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

Comment: I needed the `.txt` suffix.

Comment: Something else I am doing just brought me back here, and I didn't need the `.txt` suffix.  So I guess YMMV (or MMMV depending on the time of year).

Answer (score 31):

Have a look at [Sakiboy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47828425/2371425)!

---

## Outdated answer

From Gradle 0.9.1 the following is supported:

```groovy
android.packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
```

More information in the [Gradle release notes](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system).

Comment: This is a better solution as developers have an obligation to include these files when they use open source software.

Comment: Nice option, but this comment is totally wrong. Only the licence from the firs library will be included all the rest will be left out.

Comment: this is useful if 2 libraries are using the same .so files

Comment: Can I use that for two JARs that contain the same .class file?   I have two JARs included that both contain org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.class

Comment: Not sure. Please post a new question on Stackoverflow to get answers.

Comment: @PSIXO, you can see the answer below if you want to include ALL the licenses: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47828425/2371425

Answer (score 12):

The same problem  when I export the library httclient-4.3.5 in Android Studio 0.8.6
I need include this:

```
packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
```

The library zip content the next jar:

```
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
fluent-hc-4.3.5.jar
httpclient-4.3.5.jar
httpclient-cache-4.3.5.jar
httpcore-4.3.2.jar
httpmime-4.3.5.jar
```

Answer (score 8):

This bug still exists in  0.8+/1.10

With Jackson

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:2.2.2'
```

I had to include as well as the above suggestion before it would compile

```
exclude 'META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory'
```

Comment: how to exclude 'META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory'. Which file should I edit?

Answer (score 6):

It's more than one error

Under `apply plugin: 'android-library'`

add this ::

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
```

In case of duplicate files it's easy, look inside the `JAR` under the `META-INF` dir and see what's causing the error. It could be multiple. In my case Couchbase Lite plugin.
As you add more plugins, you will need more exceptions

Comment: Stupid question: where is that JAR file?

Comment: In Android Studio, running Gradle with the `--info`  flag let me see the log of classes being added to the apk, and I could then search upward to find the log entry for the same class being added from a different JAR.  This also showed me the file path to both JAR files.  I couldn't find a good way to choose one .class file over the other, so I modified one of the JAR files and removed the duplicate .class

Answer (score 4):

The same problem when I used 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M1' in Android Studio 1.0.1. I need include this in `build.gradle`

```
android{
...
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
android {
   packagingOptions {
       exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to include only these options in **build.gradle**:

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
```

p.s same answer from my post in : 
[Error :: duplicate files during packaging of APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467127/error-duplicate-files-during-packaging-of-apk/30911236#30911236)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do your part as developer, utilizing open source libraries, you should try including all those open source licenses within your `apk`. To do this, you can use the [merge](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html#N13103) method in your `packagingOptions`.

**Example:**

```
packagingOptions {
        // This will get include every license and notice regardless of what dir it’s in.
        merge '**/LICENSE.txt'
        merge '**/NOTICE.txt'
        merge '**/notice.txt'
        merge '**/license.txt'
        merge '**/NOTICE'
        merge '**/LICENSE'
        merge '**/notice'
        merge '**/license'
        merge '**/LGPL2.1'
        // This will exclude any README files, regardless of the dir or the file type.
        exclude '**/README.*'
}
```

This answer is better than using `pickFirst` because that method **only** picks the first license it finds and disregards all the rest, kinda rendering it useless in this case.

So in short, use the `merge` method to include all those licenses from those kickass open source libraries you’ve been using.

More info on `Gradle` [PackagingOptions](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the META-INF folder won't get filtered so multiple entries of `NOTICE` or `LICENSE` cause duplicates when building and it is tryed to copy them together.

**Dirty Quick Fix:**

Open the `.jar` file in your `.gradle/caches/...` folder (with a zip compatible tool) and remove or rename the files in the `META-INF` folder that cause the error (usally `NOTICE` or `LICENSE`).
*(I know thats also in the OP, but for me it was not really clear until I read the google forum)*

EDIT:

This was fixed in 0.7.1. Just add the confilcting files to exclude.

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry I just understand it now.

Comment: Maybe the worst possible answer : altering the jars in the gradle cache may change their checksum, and as a consequence won't work for long ... besides, thoses are not your jars

Comment: Yeah, that's why it says "Dirty Quick Fix" in bold letters. Also the correct solution is just a paragraph away. You do realise that was written at a time where there was no clean solution, but people still needed to compile their apps.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this commit comment in AOSP, the solution will be to exclude some files using DSL. Probably when 0.7.1 is released.

```
commit e7669b24c1f23ba457fdee614ef7161b33feee69
Author: Xavier Ducrohet <--->
Date:   Thu Dec 19 10:21:04 2013 -0800

    Add DSL to exclude some files from packaging.

    This only applies to files coming from jar dependencies.
    The DSL is:

    android {
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
      }
    }
```

Comment: yeah and they just wrote the release notes on the build site so hopefully they'll upload the artifact to maven central soon so we can use this!

Comment: What if I don’t want to exclude them, just rename them so they don’t collide?

Answer (score 2):

Important to know in what file it comes to this error (in you example it is META-INF/LICENSE.txt) , in my case it was in META-INF/LICENSE [without ".txt"], and then in the file META-INF/ASL2.0 so I added to my build.gradle this lines:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}
```

Very important (!) -> add the name of the file in the same style, that you see it in the error message: the text is case sensitive, and there is a difference between *.txt and *(without "txt").

Answer (score 2):

Same here with

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.oltu.oauth2:org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client:1.0.0'
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
```

I lost like 2 days for that weird error... Why is this still happening in gradle 1.0.0 ? That is very disturbing for newbies...
Anyway, thanks for that info i thought it was on my code :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I only need to add to project's build.gradle file:

```
android {
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
  }

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 1.1.0 i needed lower case names:

```
packagingOptions{
      exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Files "LICENSE.txt" and "NOTICE.txt" are case sensitive. So for SPring android library I had to add

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing .txt after LICENSE removed my error :

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
```