# Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: LICENSE.txt

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to use the jsHybugger library (www.jshybugger.com) to debug some javascript - HOWEVER - when attempting to deploy the dev build to my device I see the following error :

[image: Eclipse error]

Note: I am using Eclipse

Also, for the two projects that include the jsHybugger jar, these are the .classpath's :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/jshybugger-library-4.5.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/gson-2.2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/httpmime-4.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/icu4j-4_8_1_1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/android-support-v4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/libs/jshybugger-library-4.5.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/libs/urbanairship-lib-2.1.2.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/libs/gson-2.2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/libs/httpmime-4.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

As you can see, there's no junit included.

Comment: The two projects have their license.txt? delete one?

Comment: The complete project is made up of several sub-projects. Two of the projects include the jsHybugger library. Unfortunately, these LICENSE.TXT files are inside the jar's - is it possible to delete from within the jar ?

Comment: I tried to edit the jar using this guide: http://www.wikihow.com/Edit-the-Contents-of-a-.Jar-File-on-a-Mac however, when building the project, Eclipse complained `Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1`

Comment: I thought I was being clever, so I did the same procedure on the junit.jar, however, Eclipse again complained `while parsing junit/junit/extensions/ActiveTestSuite$1.class` ... `Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that one of the projects included junit :

[image: Project properties - Java Build Path]

So I clicked "REMOVE" to get rid of Junit 4.
This caused the test folder to become errored - and I deleted that folder !

Subsequently, I was able to deploy the project to my dev device.

**Conclusion:**
It doesn't appear to be possible to use Junit and jsHybugger at the same time until that `LICENSE.TXT" is removed by jsHybugger

Comment: LICENSE.txt was renamed to prevent name collision  (jsHybugger 4.5.3)