# Manifest mergeing - Android studio 0.8.1 upgrade build error: property 'manifestFile' does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have just upgraded to Android Studio 0.8.1 and upgraded build tools ect. from Android Studio 0.6

But then I get this build error:

> A problem was found with the configuration of task
>   ':processDevelopmentDebugResources'.
>
> File 'C:\ProjectFolder\build\manifests\DevelopmentDebug\Development\debug\AndroidManifest.xml'
>    specified for property 'manifestFile' does not exist.

But I can't figure out what the problem is. The folder manifests under build does not exists.
I suspect it has something to do with the last part of my code that replaces values in the manifest file. There is something about "Fixes in the manifest mergers" changed in build tools changelist, but I don't know if that is related. But then again - the folder does not exists and this code should change some files in it.

Any clue?

**Edit 1:** 
I just tried to comment the "variant.processManifest.doLast" part out and it works, so the issue is with this code. (Why haven't I tried that before..)
**But what has changed in the last version that make this code fail?** It worked before the upgrade.

**Edit 2:** 
See comments under *ianhanniballake*'s answer.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0.1"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0.1"
}

apt {
    arguments {
        resourcePackageName "dk.packagename"
        androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
    }
}

android {
    packagingOptions { //Fix: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20675331/860488
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 10
    buildToolsVersion "20.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 10
        buildConfigField "int", "appId", "2"
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    signingConfigs {
        //Use terminal command: gradle assembleKonnektRelease
        releaseKonnekt {

        }
    }

    productFlavors{
        def konnektSigningConfig = signingConfigs.releaseKonnekt

        Development {
            applicationId "dk.packagename"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0.0"
            buildConfigField "int", "appId", "2"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        testflight.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }

        testflight {
            applicationIdSuffix ".test"
        }

        release {
        }
    }

    // Override Data in Manifest
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.processManifest.doLast {
            copy {
                // *** SET COPY PATHS ***
                try {
                    from("${buildDir}/manifests") {
                        //println "from: ${buildDir}/manifests"
                        include "${variant.dirName}/AndroidManifest.xml"
                        //println "included: ${variant.dirName}/AndroidManifest.xml"
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    println "error: " + e
                }

                into("${buildDir}/manifests/${variant.name}")

                def variantName = variant.name.toString()
                def appName = "empty"
                def facebookId = "empty"

                // *** SET APP NAME ***
                if (variantName.contains("Development")) {
                    appName = "Development"
                } else if (variantName.contains("Konnekt")) {
                    appName = "Konnekt"
                    facebookId = "**"
                } 

                if(variantName.contains("Debug")){
                    appName = appName + " debug"
                } else if(variantName.contains("Test")){
                    appName = appName + " test"
                }

                // *** REPLACE LINES IN MANIFEST ***
                filter {
                    String line -> line.replaceAll("<application android:allowBackup=\"true\" android:icon=\"@drawable/ic_launcher\" android:label=\"todo\" android:name=\"dk.packagename.App\">", // implicit "." is replaced with: "dk.packagename."
                                                    "<application android:allowBackup=\"true\" android:icon=\"@drawable/ic_launcher\" android:label=\"" + appName + "\" android:name=\"dk.packagename.App\">");
                }
                filter {
                    String line -> line.replaceAll("<activity android:label=\"todo\" android:name=\"dk.packagename.SplashActivity\">",
                                                    "<activity android:label=\"" + appName + "\" android:name=\"dk.packagename.SplashActivity\">");
                }
                filter{
                    String line -> line.replaceAll("<meta-data android:name=\"com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId\" android:value=\"\"/>",
                                                    "<meta-data android:name=\"com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId\" android:value=\"" + facebookId + "\"/>")
                }
            }
        }

        // *** SET PATH TO NEW MANIFEST ***
        variant.processResources.manifestFile = file("${buildDir}/manifests/${variant.name}/${variant.dirName}/AndroidManifest.xml")
        //println "newManifest: ${buildDir}/manifests/${variant.name}/${variant.dirName}/AndroidManifest.xml"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing extra manifest processing when you can do that natively using the tools already available for build variants?

Comment: How would you do the things I do with build variants? Dynamic application label, set label on Activity and set meta-data? (See my edit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely due to the [new manifest merging](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger) becoming the default. One benefit of the new manifest merging is that you don't have to use this approach - instead, you can define custom placeholders and have them inserted into the merging process:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ activityLabel:"defaultName"]
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {
        }
        pro {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ activityLabel:"proName" ]
        }
    }
```

will substitute the placeholder in the following declaration:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="${activityLabel}" >
```

Note: you can also compose multiple placeholders together such as `android:label="${appName}${appType}"` to segment a string appropriately and reduce retyping the same information.

Comment: Looks like the way to go. But how can I add multiple values to the manifestPlaceholders? I can't find any syntax for it but I guess it might be something like this: `manifestPlaceholders = [ activityLabel:"defaultName", label2:"value"]`

Comment: The popossed solution to set multiple values to the manifestPlaceholders works. But `${appName}${appType}` does not work - only the first placeholder is renderet which results in: "My app name${appType}".
And when I set manifestPlaceholders from buildTypes it is ignored. Any idea how to solve those issues?

Comment: [That manifestPlaceholders is missing from buildTypes is known - please vote for this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72829)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is from this:

```
from("${buildDir}/manifests")
```

This file has been moved under `$buildDir/intermediates/manifests/`. Since your copy is in place (it seems), nothing is happening.

Then the process resource task is failing to find your modified file and it doesn't like it.

You could either update the path, or use the new manifest merger to do all the things you are trying to do in a simpler way.

Documentation is here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger