# QRCode Scanner in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

1. I want to make QRCode Scanner Application in Android Studio. 
   I found many solutions about this, but all of them open another app (like zxing).
   I want to make own layout and camera preview be in my layout. So I don't want to see another layout in my app (like zxing capture.xml)
2. I imported project zxing to my Android Studio Project. But I always get this error

   com.zxing.... does not exist

Can anybody help me?

EDİT...

The list of what I did..
1 - open a new android studio project
2 - open module settings
3 - import module and locate zxing-2.0 dir.
4 - add the dependencies (:zxing20 and core.jar)
5 - :app module Compile SDK Version 19, BuildTools Versin 19.1.0, minsdk 8, target sdk 19
6 - :zxing20 module Compile SDK Version 10, BuildTools Versin 19.1.0, minsdk 7, target sdk 7

errors:
Error:(7, 39) error: package com.google.zxing.client.android does not exist
Error:(9, 33) error: cannot find symbol class CaptureActivity
Error:(11, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(13, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(14, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)

Comment: Show us your code and point to problem

Comment: Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK C:\Users\eXistenZ\AndroidStudioProjects\QRCode9\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk<br/>Whats that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to copy some codes from Android.manifest file from zxing sources. We need to copy `Capture Activity` and `Encode activity` declarations, uses permissions and uses features. Copy them and paste into your app manifest.

[Scanning and generating barcodes using ZXING library on Android](http://michalu.eu/wordpress/scanning-and-generating-barcodes-using-zxing-library-on-android/)

Comment: Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK C:\Users\eXistenZ\AndroidStudioProjects\QRCode9\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673625/android-gradle-plugin-0-7-0-duplicate-files-during-packaging-of-apk