# Android - Apache Mime & httpClient

Tags: java, android, apache, http

I am trying to send a file to a server using HttpEntity

`HttpEntity mpEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addBinaryBody("file", file, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), file.getName()).build();`

However in order to use this I need to import the mime libraries to my project. When in my gradle.build I add:

```
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.4'
```

I am getting the following errors warnings which result in the libraries not imported:

```
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.4 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
     In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
```

Any ideas what I need to do so I can successfully import those libraries?

Comment: What if you build the app in release mode?

Comment: The exact same thing happens unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Building with gradle from command line** will do the trick.

```
 ./gradlew installDebug
```

You will see then that the prompt Android Studio gave is a warning only:

> WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.4 is ignored for Snapshot as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages

--- Here is some extra in case you meet another issue connected to apache-http ---

In my case i had to add some packaging options too due to a bug with the android-gradle-plugin:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```

For more info regarding this look into this ticket -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673625/android-gradle-plugin-0-7-0-duplicate-files-during-packaging-of-apk.