# Duplicate file exception

Tags: android

Getting this error after added the depandency
  compile 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-ima:+'

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/nanohttpd/mimetypes.properties
>           File1: C:\Users\gauravkumar.singh.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3\interactivemedia\3.5.2\21246e1a6815dc499443d46f9f5dbe954fd2b746\interactivemedia-3.5.2.jar
>           File2: C:\Users\gauravkumar.singh.android\build-cache\fe94083f69d19de3fbe36d97989e4bfe87efb104\output\jars\classes.jar

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

try this it works in my case

Add below text on build.gradle file solve problem

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude  'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
    exclude  'build-data.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Nileash , Given a quick reply will add above code and update you soon it;s working or not

Comment: I have tried but not working.My error is Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/nanohttpd/mimetypes.properties

Comment: @GhnDemo check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977396/android-studio-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-dependencies-when-compile

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests you are not excluding the META-INF/LICENSE file which exists in more than one of your dependencies

```
packagingOptions {
     exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' 
     exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
     exclude 'META-INF/notice'
     exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
     exclude 'META-INF/license'
     exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
}
```

Comment: I have tried but not working.My error is Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/nanohttpd/mimetypes.properties