# Gradle script error

Tags: android-studio, gradle

App terminates with below gradle error after two jar files added in lib folder.

**Gradle Script Error**

```
:app:packageDebug
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK C:\Users\Admin\AndroidProjects\ImageUpload\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk
    Path in archive: META-INF/LICENSE.txt
    Origin 1: C:\Users\Admin\AndroidProjects\ImageUpload\app\libs\httpmime-4.1.jar
    Origin 2: C:\Users\Admin\AndroidProjects\ImageUpload\app\libs\httpclient-4.1.jar
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
    android {
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
      }
    }
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
    File 1: C:\Users\Admin\AndroidProjects\ImageUpload\app\libs\httpmime-4.1.jar
    File 2: C:\Users\Admin\AndroidProjects\ImageUpload\app\libs\httpmime-4.1.jar
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 21.709 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: `Information:See complete output in console` what does it say?

Comment: **Logcat**
`com.imageupload D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms

com.imageupload D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1055K, 20% free 7884K/9799K, paused 9ms+6ms, total 53ms

com.imageupload D/AbsListView﹕ [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]

com.imageupload I/MotionRecognitionManager﹕ .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, listener=android.widget.AbsListView$4@428875a8
` @TimCastelijns

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Gradle plugin 0.7.0: "duplicate files during packaging of APK"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673625/android-gradle-plugin-0-7-0-duplicate-files-during-packaging-of-apk)