# Using Android SDK 18 (Jelly Bean) for Lollipop

Tags: android, eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I developed a small application using Android SDK 18 (Android 4.3) and Eclipse a few months ago. I'm trying to install the application on the same phone that is now running Android 5.1. I keep getting "**There is a Problem Parsing the Package**" error when installing the package.

I tried updating `android:targetSdkVersion` to 21 (Android 5.0) in `AndroidManifest.xml` without success.

Any idea what's going on? Here's the original `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fross.hmi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        <activity
            android:name="fross.hmi.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Any luck with my suggestion?

Comment: I'll try it tonight. That's what I was going to do anyway but it would be nice to avoid creating a new project. I doubt the problem is code-related. It's a really simple application using no fancy features. I suspect the problem is caused by a faulty configuration.

Comment: I installed Android Studio which can import project from Eclipse ADT and everything is working fine now. The gradle build script had to be edited as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20675331/208278).

Comment: Well thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a new project for android 5, copy the files over and it should tell you what the compatibility problem is, or if some code has depreciated.