# error while using firebase

Tags: android, firebase

When i'm using Firebase I always face this error !

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:

  > Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
  >   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
  >   File1: C:\Users\e171x.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.2.2\d20be6a5ddd6f8cfd36ebf6dea329873a1c41f1b\jackson-core-2.2.2.jar
  >   File2: C:\Users\e171x.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.2.2\3c8f6018eaa72d43b261181e801e6f8676c16ef6\jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar
  >   File3: C:\Users\e171x.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.2.2\285cb9c666f0f0f3dd8a1be04e1f457eb7b15113\jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar
- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--debug` option to get more log output.

which doesn't allow the emulator to run

my app gradle

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.e171x.testingonline"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"



    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })



    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: post your gradle file

Comment: Done @ManojFrekzz

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20675331/6648201

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are adding one of the JARs, namely `jackson-core-2.2.2.jar` from multiple modules. If you are using Android Studio, check in `build.gradle` files of each of your modules to check where the duplication is. You may keep it where it is accessible from all modules based on your dependency chain.

Replace:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
```

with:

```
compile('com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-bind'
    exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
})
```

Comment: I edited the post and added build.gradle , Can you check please if I have any duplication ? "

Comment: You have only one module in your project?

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
     }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: Yes and the above is my project gradle

Comment: Are you using any `JAR` files, I mean putting them in `lib` folder?

Comment: No it's empty , my all application is 1 button and 1 plaintext , Just for testing firebase

Answer (score 1):

You should not use both the legacy Firebase SDK, `com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1`, and the libraries of the new 9.x.x SDK in the same app.  They are not compatible and will interfere with each other.  Remove `com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1` and read the [Firebase Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android) for tips on code changes.