# Can RxJava and RxJava 2 coexist in the same Android project?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I have a project that uses RxJava 1. Now I'm building a module component, and thinking of starting with RxJava 2.

When perform gradle sync, all good. However during compilation I got the following error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForProductionDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/rxjava.properties
>       File1: /Users/user.name/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.2.5/b423532b5a3c949cbb799468f83bf566032fe98d/rxjava-1.2.5.jar
>       File2: /Users/user.name/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxjava/2.0.1/57f850a6b317e5582f1dbaff10a9e7d7e1fcdcfb/rxjava-2.0.1.jar

Is there anyway I could have them coexist in a single project (but different library), or this is a definitely no-no?

i.e. on one, I have

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.5'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
```

on the other one I have

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
```

Comment: Have you tried excluding some jars from gradle?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rxjava.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So regarding to [this documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#maven-address-and-base-package) they can co-exist theoretically, because the classes are located in different packages.

The error message you face is probably just caused by the android packaging into an apk, which tries to import both libraries and found a file that exists in both libs (have a look at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673625/android-gradle-plugin-0-7-0-duplicate-files-during-packaging-of-apk)).

You can ignore that file by adding the following into the "android" block of your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
    ...
}
```

However, be sure to properly test your project after that change.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for this solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude some rx properties. 
Add this:

```
android {
...
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
}
```

To your app build gradle