# Duplicate files during packaging of APK app-debug-unaligned.apk

Tags: android, http, jar, android-studio, apache-commons-httpclient

I got this error `Duplicate files during packaging of APK app-debug-unaligned.apk` when put 2 jar files :

- `httpclient-4.3.5.jar`
- `httpmime-4.3.5.jar`

  into the `libs` folder after `Sync with Gradle` and `Run`.

If user 1 jar file - `httpmime-4.3.5.jar`, I will not get this error.

Please help me how to avoid this error & still can use 2 jar files in above also,

Thanks,

p/s : I use Android Studio version 0.8.6.

`Error Detail`

> Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK 
>   ...\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk
>       Path in archive: META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
>       Origin 1: ...\app\libs\httpclient-4.3.5.jar
>       Origin 2: ...\app\libs\httpmime-4.3.5.jar

`build.gradle`

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.app'
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.0'
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')
}
```

`UPDATE` I changed from `compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')` to use Maven Link. I got same error again after put 2 maven link together:

```
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.4-alpha1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4-alpha1'
```

This is the warning

> Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4-alpha1 is
>   ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version
>   provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
>
> Warning:Dependency
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4-alpha1 is ignored for release
>   as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by
>   Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jar to change the class packages

Please help me fix.

**SOULITION** I know good answer now by addding these lines will fix `Duplicate files` error :

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```

Comment: You can replace `compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')` with this `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5'`. What version of Android studio are you using? What Version of gradle are you using?

Comment: @hoomi version 0.8.6. let me check your maven

Comment: I know why you are duplicating the dependencies `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` already includes `compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')`

Comment: Oh so u mean I should remove `compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')` right? Anyway, if I used your maven link. It is okay now. Thanks you

Comment: I am not so deep into packaging, but I don't think `exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'` will fix your dependencies problem. It will make the warning go away because you exclude the info from the JAR's meta info, but it won't solve your problem. To me, this looks like covering the oil lamp on you car's dashboard when it comes on, so it doesn't bother you anymore.

Comment: @OliverHausler You mean you have the solution, post here ok?

Comment: I don't have the solution to your problem, but as far as I can see this (if I'm wrong, correct me please), excluding dependencies from META-INF means you still have the dependencies in your Jar with a potential problem of conflict, but you don't tell the Jar what's inside. So in turn, the compiler can't detect the problem anymore and compiles without warning. This is not what you want. You want to exclude the duplicate dependency entirely. This can be done by using something like compile `compile('com.foo:foo-v4:20.0.0') { exclude module: 'fuu' }`. You will need to look at your libraries...

Comment: ... to find out which library is duplicated, and then exclude it. Look here: https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html - and as @hoomi said, you may be adding dependencies twice.

Comment: @OliverHausler : Yes, I think you are correct. These lines just compile skip warning.

Comment: after all your solution worked for me...thnx life saver

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can replace `compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')` with this compile `'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5'`.

Also you are duplicating the dependencies `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` already includes `compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')`

Comment: I get same error again after put 2 maven link, pls help me how to fix this error. If put 1 maven link, it is okay. I will unaccept your question since I want many people tell me how to fix. Thank you.

Comment: What are the two maven links that you put?

Comment: The problem is that Android is already using apache httpclient. Is there a reason that u want to reimport it?

Comment: I already update my solution in my question. I don't know why. You know?

Comment: just remove the httpclient maven line and also remove the jar file. Unless you need a new function which is not available in the older versions you do need to reimport it

Comment: No, I should use http-client, http-core ... and so the other *.jar files.

Comment: Have a look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html. If you have all the classes that you need then you can stop importing them

Comment: Ah, u see. I need use the other class had not had in Android SDK. ex. HTTPMuptile class ... u see, I want to upload multiple files ...

Comment: I am not sure if you can override android libraries. Maybe you could find the source to the classes that you need and then import them directly

Comment: You should clarify your answer again, its not easy to follow... thats why there are so many commant though

Answer (score 8):

update your build.gradle and add the following lines

```
android{
    .
    .
    .
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
```

this will fix this error. I got the same error, doing this fixed it.

Comment: sometime you need add    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

Comment: also you should add 'exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt''
  '      exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt''

Comment: @SadeqShajary you actually don't.... Only the above mentioned files are sufficient to resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

Please update this to your build.gradle file.

```
    packagingOptions { 
     exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' 
     exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated gradle now it's working

packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }

Answer (score -3):

add the below code to dependencies

compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5'
    compile (group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpmime' , version: '4.3.5') {
    exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
    }

now if you run that it will show you why it is telling duplicate may be because of META-INF/NOTICE, META-INF/LICENSE, add that first again run it may show other type. 
add all like below under android section
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }

definitely it will solve your problem.

remove all the dependancy file from the system before build.

Comment: ~"remove all the dependancy file from the system".  How is that applicable to gradle builds?

Comment: no not using the gradle build. gradle download the duplicated jars in your system. we need to physically remove the folder of the jar file from your system, before you build the project again.