# Error: duplicate files during packaging of APK after add Realm dependence to gradle

Tags: android, gradle, realm

The problem is happening after I add the Realm Library to my project. I have this dependences in my gradle project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
        compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.2'
    }
```

I Found a lot of answers in the StackOverflow and I tested many of this but i have no success. Tryied this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467127/error-duplicate-files-during-packaging-of-apk) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483410/duplicate-files-during-packaging-of-apk-app-debug-unaligned-apk) but i think my problem is something more specific.

I also added the suggestion of the LogCat error, but im getting the same error. Any answer will be appreciated.

I provide an image of the full error for a better look.

[image]

Comment: Did you try following the instructions in the error message? "You can ignore these files in your build.gradle..."?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, i added the instruction like its showing in the correctly android tag, ` exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'`. I don't know if I have to ignore other file.

Comment: You may wish to post your complete `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @CommonsWare I eidited and added the full gradle file

Comment: Try moving your `android` closure to be after the `dependencies` closure.

Comment: @CommonsWare This doesn't work. The LogCat show this error `Gradle DSL method not found: 'packagingOptions()' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `android` closure to be after the `dependencies` closure:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.2'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
}
```

> The LogCat show this error Gradle DSL method not found: 'packagingOptions()'

Then you do not have `packagingOptions` inside `android`.

Comment: It works, the problem was because i have two module. Module A is the executable and module B was the library, i was adding the `packagingOptions` block in the Module B, so this was still showing the same error, when I remove the block from Module B and add in module A it works.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `packagingOptions {` I use to typically be able to build anything so far.

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        // Exclude file to avoid
        // Error: Duplicate files during packaging of APK
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
}
```